# How do i draw an image from an array in pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyglet

I working on a voxel engine based using raycasting. But i need a way to display my frame who is a nested list like that (100x100x3). The only idea i had was to create an image in pyglet using `pyglet.image.create(width,height)` and to next modifie it's data using `image.set_data("RGB",width*3,data)`. But the problem i have is how to organize my data create like that : `numpy.zeros([100,100,3])` to be used in `set_data()`. I have try `data.tobytes()` or ctypes but i always get an image glitter with random particules.

[image]

Comment: It isn't, it's already specify in the code that the image is in RGB. No, I think i miss use the fonction or i haven't convert it in the correct format.

Comment: I have try, your solution and the problem is weirder. Now the picture as become green when it should be white and when use in a sprite and upscale the picture become in invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). `numpy.zeros([100,100,3])` generates an array of floats. You should generate an array of uint8:

<s>`numpy.zeros([100,100,3])`</s>

```py
numpy.zeros([100,100,3], dtype = numpy.uint8)
```